# Matching middle of string with grep

Tags: regex, grep

I have two files where the names may differ, but the dates of birth and gender will be the same:

```
Wheadon,Chris,4/17/1997,M
```

and

```
Wheadon,Christopher Brian,4/17/1997,M,52,40
```

If I want to pull out a match using the surname, the firstname as given in the first file (Chris in the example) and the gender and date of birth, how would I do this using grep?

Comment: Maybe using `awk -F, '{$1~/Wheadon/ && $2~/.../}' file` can be way easier.

Comment: Name handling can be difficult - are you sure you don't have any situations like "Margaret" -> "Maggie" where the shortened first name is not a prefix of the full first name?

Comment: Not clear to me what you're asking. Can you please show some examples with what should match what should not?

Comment: Of course, using awk makes far more sense as my data is in columns, thanks!

Comment: @ChrisWheadon: CAn you post some more sample data.